# Definition of static const as constexpr

Tags: c++, static, c++14, member, constexpr

```
struct CL
{
    static const int i;
};

constexpr int CL::i{};
```

Is there a valid replacement of *const* to *constexpr* in the definition of *i*? Which paragraph in the Standard can resolve it?

Comment: For variable declarations, `constexpr` implies `const`.

Comment: I do not see any benefit against `const int CL::i = 0;`, the latter, however, reads more easily and you have to type less (so for the lazy ones...). Have I missed something?

Comment: Is something wrong with `static constexpr int i = 0;` in the struct?

Comment: @md5i : You still need a definition if the variable is ever ODR-used.